# Use secant method to approximate the (local) maximum of the function $f(x)=x^2 \cot{x}, x>0$

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods, approximation, numerical-linear-algebra, secant

I'll be honest with you - as a designer, I'm not really someone who's into mathematics, but I need to solve one problem that's bugging me a lot. Can you help me to solve it? I can't find the solution in the literature. I would like to see different kinds of approaches and solutions, such that I can master my own kind of solving future problems like this one:

"Use secant method to approximate the (local) maximum of the function with precision of 3 decimal digits":
$$f(x)=x^2 \cot{x}, x>0$$,

Thank you!

Comment: There isn't a maximum over $x>0$.

Comment: Is there a local maximum? They probably wanted to say that but it's not in the text.

Comment: There are local maxima, yeah. You find critical points by solving $2x \cot(x) - x^2 \csc(x)^2=0$ which is hard enough that it has to be studied numerically.

Comment: Solved it, thanks! You should post it as an answer.